# Adding content description for for compound drawable

Tags: java, android, kotlin, accessibility

I am trying to add android accessibility to my app. I have set an image using setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds() to a textView. Is there any option to add content description to that drawable that I have added.

```
viewHolder.content.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

The **contentDescription** is added to the view, not to the drawable. If you are using a textView that has a drawable then the **contentDescription** is added to the TextView.